# Placing footer after overflowed element with height:100%

Tags: jquery, css, position, css-position

Because of certain reasons, I have this scenario:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="ng-scope">
    <p>
        [[VERY LONG TEXT]]
    </p>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%
}

#ng-scope {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
}

#footer{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/x3zbufhk/

What I want to accomplish is to place the footer at the bottom of the page, not in the middle.

So, far I have found that I can do it by using the overflow scroll or auto properties:

```
#ng-scope {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

However, I have a jQuery event triggered by $(window).scroll that stops working when I use overflow scroll or auto.

Therefore, my question, is there any other way of positioning that footer at the end?

(or alternatively: how to make the jQuery scroll event to work in that scenario)

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I want the #ng-scope element to be 100% the height of the page, even when there is a very short text. That is why I need to have html and body with height:100%. The behavior that I want is, when I have a long text:

```
html,body{
    height: auto;
}

#ng-scope {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
}

#footer{
    background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/getg811q/

And when I have a short text:

```
html,body{
    height: auto;
}

#ng-scope {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:red;
}

#footer{
    background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hcpr96ar/

I would like to obtain this behavior for long and short texts using the same css.

Answer (score 0):

If the height of the `body` element must be 100%, wrap both the `#ng-scope` div and footer inside a common parent:

http://jsfiddle.net/getg811q/

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='ng-scope'>
    a lot of content...
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Unfortunately I need html and body to be height:100% also. I want #ng-scope to be "fullscreen", but sometimes it gets overflowed and the footer goes to the wrong position...

Comment: The problem with that solution is that if I do not specify a height in #wrapper, then #ng-score has no longer the height of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/04hospnu/ . And if you put height:100% to #wrapper, you get the behavior that I want: http://jsfiddle.net/mmvbd65g/ , but that solution doesn't work when you have a long text: http://jsfiddle.net/qw44sdx8/ .